# Copy the svn:ignore files when branching

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a subversion repo with directories that contain the usual source-controlled files, but in addition to that contain files that are a dependency for execution, but not checked into source control and instead added as svn:ignore (since they would be kept in duplicates all around the repo if they were checked in into all folders). (believe me or not but there is a reason that is at least half good for having this duplication of the ignored files ;-) )

Sometimes I want to branch out and make a local copy of the directory to do a certain defined development task, and then merge back into the trunk after a couple of checkins. When I take such a copy/branch of the folder, is there a way to make it copy all the files, including the svn:ignored ones as well into the newly created branch folder working copy (what I currently do is copying them over by hand after having used tortoise to create the branch)
(but of course also still keep the :ignored files off the repo)

Many thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the answer is no, because Subversion doesn't know anything about those files, it thinks that you really want them to *always* be ignored. In fact, one of the methods of branching involves copying from one point in the repository to another (URL -> URL, whereas you are presumably talking about copying from the working copy to a branch) in which case there *are* no "ignored" files since it is copying directly between bits of the repository.

Though I don't see why the Subversion developers couldn't add a new feature to allow automatic copies of `svn:ignore`'d files when copying *from* a working copy (WC -> URL or WC -> WC).

It might not be difficult to write a script that checked the svn:ignore properties, and matched (just like svn does) those files, then copied them across too.

The command

```
svn status --no-ignore | grep '^I'
```

should give you a list of all ignored files. Pipe through `sed` to clean up the line, then `xargs` and you can quickly copy the files across. Albeit not automatically, which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to do that. The main purpose of the svn:ignore property is to NOT store ignored files on the repository. How could the server guess what files you have on your computer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

That is exactly it, I do not want them to be stored on the repo, but I need them to be copied across to the branched directory in order to be able to run the application from there.

Comment: (clarification - across to the branched directory -> across to the branched directory working copy)